# Inverse domination in the book Fundamentals of Domination in Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

The authors of the book

> *T.W. Haynes, S.T. Hedetniemi, and P.J. Slater (eds.), Fundamentals of Domination in Graphs, Marcel Dekker, Inc. New York, 1998.*

cite more than 75 variations of domination such as total domination and independent domination. I am interested in inverse domination which was introduced by Kulli and Sigarkanti in their book

> *Inverse Domination in Graphs*.

I haven't seen the Fundamentals of Domination in Graphs book and I want to knew:

**Is the inverse domination included in the book Fundamentals of Domination in Graphs?**

Comment: CAPS LOCK = CRUISE CONTROL FOR COOL. ALSO - SHOUTING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tne paper by Kulli and Sigarkanti is in the bibliography of the book, however "inverse domination" is absent in the text and in Index.

Comment: I am trying to learn domination in graphs by st-connectivity, can you guide on that? Question on this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821552/which-dominations-in-graphs-determined-by-st-connectivity) where my interest is from reliability.